# When not using a function call, how do I use rxjs timeout?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, timeout

I have an issue where timeout appears to start right once the page is loaded given how I have my current code setup.  Most of the examples that I have come across with timeout appears in part of a function call, so that is likely what is triggering when timeout actually starts for them.

For clarity I mean they may have

```js
functionName() {
 return this.http.get(this.url).
  pipe(
  timeout(5000)
 )
}
```

As you can see in my code below, my observable is setup upon creation right away. I've tried using timeout as directed in documentation, but that appears be using that function approach.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private baseAPIURL: string = environment.baseAPIUrl;
  private apiUrl = `${this.baseAPIURL}/Product/GetProduct`;

  private searchSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ProductSearch>(null);

  searchSelectedAction$ = this.searchSubject.asObservable();

    productOutput$ = this.searchSelectedAction$
    .pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(searchCriteria =>
        this.http.get<ProductResults>(`${this.apiUrl}/${searchCriteria.key1}/${searchCriteria.key2}`, { observe: 'response' })),
      timeout(5000),
      map(response => [response.body]),
      tap(data => console.log(data))
    );

  getProductResults(searchCriteria: ProductSearch): void {
    this.searchSubject.next(searchCriteria);
  }
}
```

Expected result is to have the http request cancelled after 5 seconds and an error displayed that the request has been cancelled.

Actual result right now is that once the page loads the timeout starts right away without even having done a search.

I am using RxJS 6.  My html is just setup to subscribe to productOutput$ using an async pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your question, this can be solved with either:

1. Use `Subject` and not `BehaviourSubject`, or..
2. Use `filter(x=> x !== null)` prior to the HTTP call. This will ensure that none of the operators after the filter will get called. Feel free to update the `filter` operator according to your need

Comment: It doesn't seem like either of these work.  I totally understood why you suggested the Subject over Behaviorsubject as it made sense when I thought about it.  I also tried the filter method and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It turns out the answer is to pipe the http response and put the timeout inside there.  Thank you!